# asp.net web page request post parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, webrequest

With the code below I can request a page with post parameters. But the page requested couldn't get the parameters. I put two textboxes to the requested page and send parameters to this page. What is wrong with this code?

```
private string PostForm(string _targetUrl, string _parameter1, string _parameter2)
{

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(_targetUrl);

    request.Method = "POST";

    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    string postContent = string.Format("Textbox1={0}&Textbox2={1}", _parameter1, _parameter2);

    byte[] postContentBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postContent);

    request.ContentLength = postContentBytes.Length;

    Stream writer = request.GetRequestStream();

    writer.Write(postContentBytes, 0, postContentBytes.Length);

    writer.Close();

    HttpWebResponse testResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    if (!testResponse.StatusDescription.Equals("OK", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        Response.Write("Error");
    }

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(testResponse.GetResponseStream());
    string returnvalue = sr.ReadToEnd();

    return returnvalue;
}
```

Comment: You should post the form also.

Comment: How can I post the requested page's form? For sample I didn't put a button to the page. Should I put a submit button and call it? If yes how?

Comment: I can read parameters with `Request.Form["Textbox1"]`. But the page can't set textbox value as soon as page requested.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that "name" of textbox inputs on the target page are `Textbox1` and `Textbox2`.

Comment: `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:textbox ID="Textbox1" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
    <asp:textbox ID="Textbox2" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
</asp:Button>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: You want the page to display with values in textbox inputs? You can't do like this (viewstates, aspnet validation...). But I don't understand what you want to do...

Comment: It is a sample form. I want to send parameters to an external url and submit that form.